# MySQL Order By Combining Values in Two Fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns, ai1 and ai2.  Both are float(6,2) fields, and contain values like below:

```
ai1      ai2
195.00   193.75
190.60   192.85
189.63   180.00
```

I would like to be able to sort the data in descending order regardless of the column that contains the value.  In other words, like this:

```
195.00
193.75
192.85
190.60
189.63
180.00
```

I made a feeble attempt at an IF statement in my Order By which failed.  I've also searched here and seen many references to using CASE, but I don't know if that would apply here or how it would work if it does.

I appreciate any guidance.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that these should be float and not decimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

combined them using `UNION`

```
SELECT ai1 ai FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT ai2 ai FROM tablename
ORDER BY ai DESC
```

by the way, specifying `ALL` will keep duplicate value. If you want to display only unique values remove `ALL` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This will now lead me in the right direction.